# rails active record to fetch result from multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have the following query

```
SubCategory.joins(dropdown_heads: :dropdown_lists).where(id: params[:sub_cat_id])
```

The above query generates

```
SELECT "sub_categories".* FROM "sub_categories" INNER JOIN "dropdown_heads" ON "dropdown_heads"."sub_category_id" = "sub_categories"."id" INNER JOIN "dropdown_lists" ON "dropdown_lists"."dropdown_head_id" = "dropdown_heads"."id" WHERE "sub_categories"."id" = 6
```

But what I actually need is to fetch records from `dropdown_heads` and `dropdown_lists` only.

What modification do I need to achieve it?

Following are the associations

**sub_category.rb**

```
has_many: dropdown_heads
```

**dropdown_head.rb**

```
has_many: dropdown_lists
belongs_to: sub_category
```

**dropdown_lists.rb**

```
belongs_to: dropdown_head
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve the sub_category record from the database

```
@sub_category = SubCategory.find(params[:sub_cat_id])
```

Retrieve all dropdown_heads

```
sub_category.dropdown_heads
```

Iterate through dropdown_head to retrieve dropdown_lists

```
@sub_category.dropdown_heads {|dropdown_head| dropdown_head.dropdown_lists} #do whatever you want with dropdown_lists
```

which is same as:

```
@sub_category.dropdown_heads.each |dropdown_head|
 dropdown_head.dropdown_lists
end
```

Comment: you only need to get sub_category from the controller.  once you have the correct sub_category object, you can do the rest in your views

Comment: Had this in my view `<%= sub_category.dropdown_heads %>` but throwing exception `undefined local variable or method `sub_category'`

Comment: make sub_category an instance variable (add "@" prefix, see my updated answer)

Comment: I cant understand what is happening in your third code. Can you please explain it

Comment: it iterates through each dropdown_head from a collection a sub_category.dropdown_heads to retrieve dropdown_lists (for each dropdown_head).

Comment: ok ill paste my code i did something wrong there. Can you check it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40063/discussion-between-rb512-and-seting)

Comment: To reduce the number of SQL queries, you can use eager-loading: `@sub_category.dropdown_heads.includes(:dropdown_lists)`

Comment: This is good. But you can do it in one query:                         `@sub_category = SubCategory.find(id).includes(dropdown_heads: :dropdown_lists)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to get the sub_category instance, you can just call

```
    dropdown_heads = DropdownHead.find_all_by_sub_category_id(params[:sub_cat_id])
```

and the remaining are just the same as @rb512 said.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SubCategory.joins(dropdown_heads: :dropdown_lists).where(id: params[:sub_cat_id].select("dropdown_heads.dropdown_heads, dropdown_lists.dropdown_lists")
```

Even you can use `pluck()` method of rails to retrieve specific fields.